# How to delete the reflected row of the second JTable if the user selects another row in the first JTable?

Tags: java, if-statement, user-interface, multidimensional-array, row

I am having trouble deleting the previous row of my second table of my Products Stock In GUI in Java.

[image: User's first attempt of selecting a row]

[image: User selects another row]

The flow of the functionality of my GUI is this:

1. If the user will select a row in the first table of the GUI, the values of those rows will be reflected on the second rows
2. If the user will select another/different row in the first table, the previous reflected row which was selected in the first table must be deleted and is replaced by the current selected row.

To sum it up, I have to replace/delete the previous reflected rows if I will select a different row in the first table then replace that previous selected row into the current selected row.

Here's my source code:

```java
private void firstTableMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
  DefaultTableModel secondTblmodel = (DefaultTableModel) secondTable.getModel();
  int selectPRoww = firstTable.getSelectedRow();
  for (int x = 0; x < ProductAllData2[selectPRoww].length; x++) {
    //ProductAllData2 is a 3D array
    if (ProductAllData2[selectPRoww][x][0] != null) {
      if (setRowCountID2 == 0)
        secondTblmodel.setRowCount(0);
      //Reflects and displays the values of the selected
      // row from the first table to the second table
      secondTblmodel.addRow(ProductAllData2[selectPRoww][x]);
      // deletes previous row if index of selected row is
      // greater than the previous selected row (doesn't work)
      if (selectPRoww > selectPRoww) {
        secondTblmodel.removeRow(selectPRoww - 1);
      }
      // deletes previous row if index of selected row is
      // less than the previous selected row (doesn't work)
      if (selectPRoww < selectPRoww) {
        secondTblmodel.removeRow(selectPRoww + 1);
      }
      setRowCountID2++;
    }
  }
}
```

Am I missing something in my functionality or do I need to modify the for loops?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, your logic should not be like this.

As the second table (View) depends on the selection of the first table, then the second table should always be cleared, then you do this logic.

```java
//Reflects and displays the values of the selected
// row from the first table to the second table
secondTblmodel.addRow(data);
```

Important Point: Please use ListSelectionListener on table1, rather than depending on mouse clicks.

Example of usage:

```java
table1.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new SharedListSelectionHandler());
```

```java
class SharedListSelectionHandler implements ListSelectionListener {
    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
        ListSelectionModel lsm = (ListSelectionModel) e.getSource();

        int firstIndex = e.getFirstIndex();
        int lastIndex = e.getLastIndex();
        boolean isAdjusting = e.getValueIsAdjusting();
        output.append("Event for indexes "
                + firstIndex + " - " + lastIndex
                + "; isAdjusting is " + isAdjusting
                + "; selected indexes:");

        if (lsm.isSelectionEmpty()) {
            output.append(" <none>");
        } else {
            // Find out which indexes are selected.
            int minIndex = lsm.getMinSelectionIndex();
            int maxIndex = lsm.getMaxSelectionIndex();
            for (int i = minIndex; i <= maxIndex; i++) {
                if (lsm.isSelectedIndex(i)) {
                    output.append(" " + i);
                }
            }
        }
        output.append(newline);
    }
}
```

[How to Write a List Selection Listener | The Java™ Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/listselectionlistener.html)

Similar StackOverflow: [Deleting row from JTable after valueChanged event is triggered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11640905/deleting-row-from-jtable-after-valuechanged-event-is-triggered)